# Integrate Stanford NER in my application/ call web service

Tags: web-services, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am building an application in ASP .NET and want to use Stanford-Ner within my application.
Any idea on how to integrate it? 
I couldn't find the web service to use as well, do they have one?

I would like this functionality within my application: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/
Either as a web service or by integrating.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See this FAQ answer: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#cc

Answer (score 0):

You can run it locally: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml

Comment: that is what I m currently doing. But i want this application to be integrated with my ASP.Net application. Are there any means to achieve this ?